# Shortest path algorithm that passes through certain edges

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, edges

I need to find the shortest path in a graph that passes through at least one edge marked as "must pass". Any ideas? Could Dijkstra's algorithm be modified in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the path from A to B that must pass through C, compute it as two shortest paths, one from A to C, and another from C to B.

Comment: I don't see how that could help me. I need it to pass through certain edges, not nodes.

Comment: Why dont you place a node in the edge then?

Comment: I didn't think about that. Seems like an interesting approach. Although, that complicates my graph and algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could try C as being the vertex either end of the edge and use the shortest of the two results.